# ListView doesnot show updated list value. But column does

Tags: listview, flutter

I have a list

```
List tasksList = <Widget>[
    Text('task1'),
    Text('task2'),
  ];
```

In the code when user adds new task I add it to the list  as follows:

```
widget.tasksList.add(
   Text('task3'),
);
```

An expanded widget ***column*** shows the recent addition of `'task3'` nicely:

```
Column(
  children: this.tasksList,
),
```

But when I use ***ListView*** I dont see `'task3'`

```
ListView(
  children: this.tasksList,
),
```

Is there something special I need to do to refresh the ListView as compared to a column widget?
Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `setState`?

Comment: yes. And that's why Column widget updates successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions I know of

1) Use `ListView.builder`

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: tasksList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return tasksList[index];
    }
)
```

2) Wrap column inside listview

```
ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
        Column(
            children: tasksList,
        )
    ],
)
```